# I'm having some parts in my object that I can't texturize

Tags: texturing, uv, objects, texture-painting

I'm kinda new and have been unable to resolve this by myself (I have googled it for more than a day and didn't find a case that coincides with mine).

The thing is that I made this object by copying and joining the hinges (because it would be impossible for me to make the same object twice with the same marked seams) to the door.

Then I unwrapped it and disposed to texture paint but it didn't work on the hinges; so I tried by exporting the UV Map, paint it in photoshop and the apply it, but that also didn't work.

Here is how the door is looking:
[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2rHXrRBr0-ek82UDltWjllYzA/view

And here is the texture with the uv map overlaid:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2rHXrRBr0-ZkpHa3RaUjJVQnM/view

Do you know what could I have done wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Do you have several materials for your object ? If yes, probably the hinges material does not use the texture

Comment: No, just 1 material and 1 texture :/

Comment: I think if you share your blend file here, this can help to understand what is happening for your question http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I looked at the file, and I noticed you had about 10 materials initiated but not assigned to anything, so after I deleted them the hinge was able to take the material assigned to the other faces of the door.

Comment: Did that make sense? Just go into your materials and delete al the extra slots.